# Error with WEB3js - NodeJs.utils in vite react ts app - How to resolve TypeError: callbackify is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web3js, vite

Hey I am playing around with web3 inside react as a client application (using vite react-ts) and trying to call `web3.eth.net.getId()` but this will throw me an error that `callbackify is not a function` I digged a little and found an old issue on the github which states that older versions of Nodejs.util (prior version 0.11) didn't have this function. So I checked the package.json where the error occurs (web3-core-requestmanager) it has "util":"^0.12.0", so callbackify should be available.

In fact when I am looking at their imports, they seem to be able to import it:
(following code is `./node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js`

```js
const { callbackify } = require('util');
```

but when they want to use it, callbackify is undefined

```js
//RequestManager.prototype.send function
const callbackRequest = callbackify(this.provider.request.bind(this.provider));
```

I tried to play around with the dependencies and tried different versions of web3.js (1.7.3; 1.6.0; 1.5.1) all of them had the same util dependency (0.12.0).

My code in all this matter looks like this:

```js
class Blockchain {
  public blockchainBaseUrl: string;
  public web3;
  public provider;
  public account: string = '';
  public contract: any;
  constructor() {
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_BLOCKCHAIN_BASE_URL === undefined) {
      throw new Error('REACT_APP_BLOCKCHAIN_BASE_URL is not defined');
    }
    this.provider = window.ethereum;
    if (this.provider === undefined) {
      throw new Error('MetaMask is not installed');
    }
    this.setUpInitialAccount();
    this.addEthereumEventListener();
    this.blockchainBaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BLOCKCHAIN_BASE_URL;
    this.web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || this.blockchainBaseUrl);
    this.setContract();
  }

  async setContract() {
    // error comes from the next line
    const networkId = await this.web3.eth.net.getId();

    this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(
      // @ts-ignore
      Token.abi,
      // @ts-ignore
      Token.networks[networkId].address
    );
  }
}
```

I also was told that I should simply add a `.catch()` to `web3.eth.net.getId()` but this did nothing. Am I doing something wrong or is this a dependency problem? If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Do I need to expose the util API to the browser somehow? To me, it seems that the API is simply not available.

This is should be the relevant part of my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import GlobalsPolyfills from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
import NodeModulesPolyfills from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      plugins: [
        NodeModulesPolyfills(),
        GlobalsPolyfills({
          process: true,
          buffer: true,
        }),
      ],
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here is my complete vite config
https://pastebin.com/zvgbNbhQ

**Update**

By now I think that I understand the issue - it seems that it is a VIte-specific problem and I need to polyfill the NodeJs.util API. I am already doing this (at least I thought). Perhaps someone can provide some guidance on what I am doing wrong with my config?

**Update 2**

I actually have now the util API inside the browser, but it is still giving me the same error. This is my new config:
https://pastebin.com/mreVbzUW I can even log it out:
[image: Error Message with callbackify function on top]

**Update 3**

SO I am still facing this issue - I tried a different approach to polyfill I posted the update to the github issue https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/4992#issuecomment-1117894830

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem with vue3 + vite + we3

It's started from errors: `process in not defined` than `Buffer is not defined` and finally  after I configure polyfill I came to  `callbackify is not defined`

Did a lot of researches and finally solved this issue with next trick:

- Rollback all polyfill configurations
- Add to the head html file

```
<script>window.global = window;</script>
<script type="module">
    import process from "process";
    import { Buffer } from "buffer";
    import EventEmitter from "events";
    
    window.Buffer = Buffer;
    window.process = process;
    window.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
</script>
```

- vite.config.ts

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      process: "process/browser",
      stream: "stream-browserify",
      zlib: "browserify-zlib",
      util: 'util'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ]
}
```

add these dependencies browserify-zlib, events, process, stream-browserify, util

Source https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3817#issuecomment-864450199

Hope it will helps you

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, I am already doing this. But it seems something else is wrong. Because I am already doing the polyfilling part.