# "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined" with Vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, aws-sdk, vite

I'm getting the error from the title in my Vue app with Vite. I seem to have tried everything that I could find online but nothing really seems to work in my case.

The problem started when I installed `aws-sdk` to connect to my linode bucket storage, and importing it like `import aws from 'aws-sdk'`.

I tried almost everything from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114775/vite-global-is-not-defined) issue, and quite a few variants from that in vite.config.js that I found elsewhere.

When using the following in my vite.config.js it works in dev:

```
define: {
   global: "window",
},
```

But gives me the following error in prod:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "aws-sdk" from "/var/www/html/kwigy/src/linode.js".
[...]
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
[...]
```

And that doesn't seem to be a good solution anyway according to what I found online.

Adding a script to the  tag or making a file that imports the said script in `main.js` also works in dev but gives the same error in prod.

I also tried to install [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2), to use it as `const aws = require('aws-sdk')` but I have to admit I do not really understand how to configure that from the docs.

Does anybody have a solution to my problem? I have been stuck for a full day on this now.

Comment: Had the same problem.
Found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114775/vite-global-is-not-defined