# How to add global variable if not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

When d3.js moved to version 4, there was a significant rewrite of the Api, and also a change to modular packaging.

I don't want to upgrade to version 4 of d3.js but I have to rewrite the react/redux web app portion of my project using Vite, and  version 3 of d3.js and it's use of global is not compatible with the JavaScript modular system used by Vite.

The error I'm getting is that "global" is not defined, and version 3 of d3.js uses "global."

This is what it says it `node_modules/d3/index.js (index.js:4:13)`

```
var globals = {};

// Stash old global.
if ("d3" in global) globals.d3 = global.d3;

module.exports = require("./d3");

// Restore old global.
if ("d3" in globals) global.d3 = globals.d3; else delete global.d3;
```

Therefore, I commented out that reference to global in the d3/index.js file to see what would happen, and I got a similar property, "cannot read properties of undefined (document)" This is the source code

```
var d3_document = this.document;
function d3_documentElement(node) {
  return node && (node.ownerDocument || node.document || node).documentElement;
}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the shift to modular d3 in version 4, but d3.js version 3.5.5 works fine when I don't use it with Vite.js. For example, if I just source it in an index.html file and run it with an http-server.

Question: is there a way to configure Vite.js to make it work with d3.js version 3.5.5? or can I alter the d3.js version 3.5.5 source code to make it run on Vite.js?

Update

I added this to the Vite.config.js

```
  define: {
    global: {},
    document: {}
  }
```

Now Vite complains that the property `document` cannot be set on `#<Window>.`

`3env.ts:24  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property document of #<Window> which has only a getter`

This [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114775/vite-global-is-not-defined)  question helps but it doesn't explain when "document" is undefined and it can't be "set" on Window.

Probably irrelevant but here's the source code for d3 version 3.5.5 on unpkg.com
[d3 version 3.5.5](https://unpkg.com/browse/d3@3.5.5/d3.js)`

Here's the source code for d3 version 4 on unpkg.com
[d3 version 4](https://unpkg.com/browse/d3@4.0.0/build/d3.js)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/72114775/51685 help?

Comment: @AKK yes, it does help a lot, at least it explains that I can define things in the Vite.config.js.  However, (see update in OP). I can't set "document" on Window.

Comment: `document` will always be set, though.

Comment: @AKX that's what I assumed  but this is the error message: `Cannot read properties of undefined (document) `:  `var d3_document = this.document;`

Comment: If altering the d3 source is an option then can't you just give it the `this` parameter explicitly? You'd only have to put `.call(window)` or `.call(globalThis)` at the end of the file, so it would look like this `(function(){...}).call(window)`, instead of like this `!function(){...}()`. Their code works in a simple `index.html` file because by default `this` is `window`. The fact that their code uses `this` makes it easy to supply a custom object.

Comment: @zoran404 this is a good fallback option. My bounty said I'd prefer a solution involving the Vite config, but if it doesn't come I will give you the bounty, but you'd have to post an answer.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to only use the config. I can check later. This is just the first solution that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `node_modules/d3/d3.js` file uses the `this` keyword.
Specifically it reads `this.document`, instead of `window.document` or simply directly accessing the global `document` variable.
So the actual question should be: Is it possible to define `this` for d3 in Vite.

You saw that d3 worked fine when you tested with your http-server where you load the script from a `index.html` file.

It worked because you loaded it using `<script type="text/javascript">`.
This is because in old script files the default value for top-level `this` is `window`.

If you tried loading it using `<script type="module">`, like Vite does, it wouldn't have worked, since for module scripts the top-level `this` variable is `undefined`.

---

Vite does have an option for replacing variables by defining replacements in `vite.config.js`, but it has a lot of limitations because of the way it is implemented:

> [Entries will be defined as globals during dev and statically replaced during build.](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define)

In dev mode this is useless for us, since you can not define `this` as a global variable. And implicitly we can't define a replacement for `this.document` either.

During build we have a similar problem for a different reason. Vite can replace `this`, but only in the top level. Unfortunately d3 is wrapped in a `function(){}` and Vite does not want to replace `this` inside of functions, since `this` is seen as a local variable and Vite doesn't want to replace local variables.
It doesn't matter if you tried defining `this:'window'` or if you try being specific by defining `'this.document':'window.document'`.

I haven't found anything else in docs that might be useful to us, so it is likely not possible to solve the problem using Vite config.

I'm guessing they didn't want to go against the official default, so they didn't create an option for this.

And unfortunately `this` is not something you can polyfill yourself.

---

This leaves us only with the solution I mentioned yesterday in the comments, that is editing the d3 source. At least the change is very minor.

First copy `node_modules/d3/d3.js` file to your source folder.
(you should never edit files in `node_modules` since npm or yarn might overwrite those changes; and pnpm even uses symbolic links, so it shared the same file for all projects)

Then you'd have to replace the first and last lines from:

```js
!function() {
  // ...
}()
```

to:

```js
(function() {
  // ...
}).call(window)
```

And of course you have to replace your import statements to import this new file instead of importing d3 from node_modules.

---

As for `node_modules/d3/index.js` you can actually skip that file instead of adding polyfills for it.
In later patches like `3.5.17` it was even removed.
All it does is handle the global d3 variable.